# How to set value of <pre> html tag using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I tried using sendKeys() method on webelement but it does not work. Does anyone has any idea if this can be achieved ?

Please find below the html.

```
<div class="CodeMirror-code" style="">
 <div style="position: relative;">
 <div style="position: absolute; left: -51px;">
 **<pre>**
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do it manually? A pre is not a textarea, so you can't write anything to it.

Comment: well when i am writing anything in the provided box, it goes into this <pre> tag.

Comment: Does this element already exists?

Comment: yes, the html structure shown in the question which contains this tag already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@class="CodeMirror-code"]//p'));
      js.executeScript('arguments[0].innerHTML = "text goes here";', element);
```